# Trouble getting OpenCV framework symbols to link in XCode

Tags: opencv, titanium, xcode4.5

I'm missing something minor here in my project using the OpenCV framework from a working demo.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download the example app from http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/
2. Create a new Titainum iOS module with titanium create --platform=iphone --type=module --dir=. --name=opencv --id=opencv
3. Open the XCode project, drag in the OpenCV framework from the FaceTracker app and the other required frameworks.
4. Add OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -framework OpenCV to module.xcconfig
5. Create new TiUIView and TiUIViewProxy classes named OpencvView and OpencvViewProxy.
6. In the new OpencvView class, instantiate a UIViewController that uses OpenCV.

The build will build the Titanium module, but when I try to run the module test harness, I get these errors for OpenCV objects:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer", referenced from:
      -[VideoCaptureViewController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libopencv.a(VideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "_CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp", referenced from:
      -[VideoCaptureViewController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libopencv.a(VideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "_CMTimeMake", referenced from:
      -[VideoCaptureViewController createCaptureSessionForCamera:qualityPreset:grayscale:] in libopencv.a(VideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress", referenced from:
      -[VideoCaptureViewController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libopencv.a(VideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane", referenced from:
      -[VideoCaptureViewController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libopencv.a(VideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetHeight", referenced from:
      -[VideoCaptureViewController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libopencv.a(VideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType", referenced from:
      -[VideoCaptureViewController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libopencv.a(VideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetWidth", referenced from:
      -[VideoCaptureViewController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libopencv.a(VideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress", referenced from:
      -[VideoCaptureViewController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libopencv.a(VideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress", referenced from:
      -[VideoCaptureViewController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libopencv.a(VideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)", referenced from:
      -[DemoVideoCaptureViewController processFrame:videoRect:videoOrientation:] in libopencv.a(DemoVideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)", referenced from:
      -[DemoVideoCaptureViewController processFrame:videoRect:videoOrientation:] in libopencv.a(DemoVideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "cv::CascadeClassifier::load(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      -[DemoVideoCaptureViewController viewDidLoad] in libopencv.a(DemoVideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "cv::CascadeClassifier::CascadeClassifier()", referenced from:
      -[DemoVideoCaptureViewController .cxx_construct] in libopencv.a(DemoVideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "cv::CascadeClassifier::~CascadeClassifier()", referenced from:
      -[DemoVideoCaptureViewController .cxx_destruct] in libopencv.a(DemoVideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "cv::Mat::deallocate()", referenced from:
      -[VideoCaptureViewController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libopencv.a(VideoCaptureViewController.o)
      -[UIImage(UIImage_OpenCV) CVMat] in libopencv.a(UIImage+OpenCV.o)
      -[UIImage(UIImage_OpenCV) CVGrayscaleMat] in libopencv.a(UIImage+OpenCV.o)
  "cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int)", referenced from:
      -[UIImage(UIImage_OpenCV) CVMat] in libopencv.a(UIImage+OpenCV.o)
      -[UIImage(UIImage_OpenCV) CVGrayscaleMat] in libopencv.a(UIImage+OpenCV.o)
  "cv::flip(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int)", referenced from:
      -[DemoVideoCaptureViewController processFrame:videoRect:videoOrientation:] in libopencv.a(DemoVideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "cv::resize(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::*OutputArray const&, cv::Size*, double, double, int)", referenced from:
      -[DemoVideoCaptureViewController processFrame:videoRect:videoOrientation:] in libopencv.a(DemoVideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "cv::fastFree(void*)", referenced from:
      -[VideoCaptureViewController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libopencv.a(VideoCaptureViewController.o)
      -[UIImage(UIImage_OpenCV) CVMat] in libopencv.a(UIImage+OpenCV.o)
      -[UIImage(UIImage_OpenCV) CVGrayscaleMat] in libopencv.a(UIImage+OpenCV.o)
  "cv::transpose(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&)", referenced from:
      -[DemoVideoCaptureViewController processFrame:videoRect:videoOrientation:] in libopencv.a(DemoVideoCaptureViewController.o)
  "_kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey", referenced from:
      -[VideoCaptureViewController createCaptureSessionForCamera:qualityPreset:grayscale:] in libopencv.a(VideoCaptureViewController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Are you trying to build for the simulator? I suspect the framework you have downloaded is only built for ARM processors.

Comment: I'm starting to think that too. But, I tried to use the module in Titanium Studio and install directly to the device. I got the same type of "SystemExit: 65" error. Is it possible to develop a Ti iOS module that employs a framework only build for the device?

Comment: Hi Joe, did you solve this? I am facing the very same problem when building for Titanium Appcelerator. The module builds correctly, but when I try to compile and run the App, I get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the default apple llvm compiler on Xcode 4.5.1. Try changing it to gcc (from your build options) and see if this works.

Comment: Hi. I have a problem just like the one in this question. Please, how do I change my Compiler to GCC? I'm using Xcode 11.3.1 and there is are two options on `Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C`, which is `Default Compiler (Apple Clang)` and `Other`. The `Other` field, requires to enter manually some information about the compiler. Please help me, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I have similar errors. And just changing "build setting" does not help.

Finally, I solved this problem by adding some framework like coreMedia, coreVideo, etc.
These frameworks, however, are not used in my code.

So I guess openCV needs these frameworks. But I don't know why.

Hope this will help:)